# Boolean variable initialization used in several components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I realize an instant messenger. When I click on a thread, a window should open with the desired discussion. I do not want the user to open two identical discussions. This is why I added a boolean 'isOpen' variable to each thread :

```
export class Thread {

id: string;
messages: Observable<Message[]>;
lastMessage: Message = null;
participants: User[];
isOpen: boolean;
isReduce: boolean;
isFlash: boolean;

constructor(id?: string,
          participants?: User[],
          messages?: Observable<Message[]>,
          obj?: any) {
this.id             = id                       || uuid();
this.participants   = participants;
this.messages       = messages;
this.isOpen         = obj && obj.isOpen        || false;
this.isReduce       = obj && obj.isReduce      || false;
this.isFlash        = obj && obj.isFlash       || true;
 }
}
```

When I click on a thread, the variable 'thread.isOpen' changes to true.
And when I close this thread, the variable 'thread.isOpen' goes to false :

```
export class ListItemComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input() thread: Thread;
      ............................
clicked(thread: Thread): void {
this.newWindow = true;
if (!thread.isOpen) {
  thread = this.chatService.openThread(thread);
  this.chatService.setCurrentThread(thread);
  thread.isOpen = true;
 }
}

export class WindowItemComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() thread: Thread;
      ..............................
closeThread(thread?: Thread): void {
document.getElementById('chat-window-' + this.thread.id).style.display = 'none';
thread.isOpen = false;
this.newUser = false;
this.newWindow = false;
}
```

I do not understand why it does not work. When I test my variable this does not keep the initialization set to true. My two functions are in two different components.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT

```
@Injectable()
  export class ChatService {
openThread(thread: Thread): Thread {
const newThread: Thread = new Thread(thread.id, thread.participants, thread.messages);
this.threadService.windows.push(newThread);
return newThread;
}

setCurrentThread(newThread: Thread): void {
  this.threadService.currentThread.next(newThread);
}
```

Comment: I can't see nothing about rxjs in there related with the isOpen. would be great if you post the _chatService.openThread_ . the thread  you use is not in the component. Could you explain from were is comming?

Comment: @kimy82
I published my post. 
Which thread are you talking about? The one that is in parameter of the function openThread?

Comment: Yes @Floriane , I do not see where is the thread instance living. The think is that I would make the thread as an angular component because I guess that it has a html associated.

Comment: @kimy82
I added details in my post.
The parameter given to the function openThread() is taken as parameter of the function cliked (thread)

Comment: so the thread is an input but in clicked function you use _ thread.isOpen = true;_ instead of _this.thread.isOpen = true;_ and the input thread is not changed. Why?

Comment: Something being open is a UI/UX issue. I would not pollute the data representation for that object with such UI-specific information.

Comment: @kimy82
Sorry but I'm not sure to understand ..
Is what i have to use this.thread.isOpen in my two components?
Because if I use this.thread.isOpen in the two components, this will not change the value of the same boolean isOpen

Comment: @kimy82
And I need to put @Input() thread: Thread, for the HTML : 
<window-item
    *ngFor="let thread of windows"
    [thread]="thread">
  </window-item>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to paste and example and I hope that will help.

Imagine you have a parent component with some fake threads which might be comming from a rest call in real live:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  private threads: any[] = [{isOpen: false, id: '1'}, {isOpen: false, id: '2'}];
}
```

with its html that is spreading the objects to its childdren:

```
<div>

  <child *ngFor="let thread of threads"  [thread]="thread"></child>
  <child *ngFor="let thread of threads"  [thread]="thread"></child>

    <div *ngFor="let t of threads">{{t.isOpen}} </div>
</div>
```

When you do this and you change the thread object within its childdren. The thread object will change everywhere, in the parent and in all other childdren.

The child component is something like (It is a very simple child displaying the isOpen attribute and with a change method to change it from false to true):

```
export class child implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public thread: any;

  public change(){
    this.thread.isOpen = true;
  }
}
```

with the html :

```
<div (click)="change()">{{thread.isOpen}}</div>
```

Hope that helps. As you can see I am trying to prove that it doesnt't matter where you change the isOpen property it will effect everywhere in the application

Comment: Thanks for your answer !! I think I understand what you're saying. However, by changing my code, it still does not work. When I open a window and close it, I can not open it. Initialization done in my closeThread function is not taken into account : 

`clicked(thread: Thread): void {
    if (!this.thread.isOpen) {
      thread = this.chatService.openThread(thread);
      this.chatService.setCurrentThread(thread);
      this.thread.isOpen = true;
    }
  }`

`closeThread(thread?: Thread): void {
    this.thread.isOpen = false;
  }`

Comment: Be aware that your _threadService.openThread_ is creating a new Thread instead of modifying the existing one. That will  create a new object that will not populate changes around

Comment: Thank you very much I had not seen this.
It works, but there is a bug when I open a window and then close it several times.
I can not close the window anymore.
Do you know why ?

Comment: When you do _this.threadService.windows.push(newThread);_ you are adding a new thread but when you close it you are not removing it. Hence, you will end up having the same thread multiple times in the array. Another thing is that what you do when closing the thread I wouldn't use use document.getElementById ... I would use and *ngIf="isOpen" angular property for hidding/showing the element

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it works perfectly by adding * ngIf and deleting my object in my array.